# Rename constant term using stargazer

Tags: r, stargazer

I'd like to add the control group mean to my regression tables in `Stargazer`. My current idea is to replace the intercept with the control group mean and rename that term. I know how to replace the value of the intercept, but is there a way to rename the intercept term? It's often informative to replace the constant term with the control group mean.

```
library(stargazer)

attitude$treatment <- rbinom(n = 30, size = 1, prob = .5)
lm_model <- lm(rating ~ treatment + complaints + privileges + learning 
           + raises + critical, data=attitude)

#add in control mean
control_mean <- mean(attitude[attitude$treatment == 0, "rating"])
lm_model[["coefficients"]][names(lm_model[["coefficients"]]) == 
                         "(Intercept)"] <- control_mean

stargazer(lm_model)
```

Comment: Can you post a small sample of your data so that we can run your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Rename intercept
names(lm_model$coefficients)[1]

# Change value of intercept to control_mean
lm_model$coefficients[1] = control_mean
```

This isn't really a `stargazer` question, but is just a matter of how to modify a model object.

Comment: Yup, that's a much easier way to go about it. Thanks!